# NodeJS communicating through a tree of sub-processes

Tags: node.js, child-process, piping

I am designing a NodeJS app that downloads, parses, and uses basic machine learning techniques on publicly available data from a handful of different sources. This can be computationally expensive, and in order to avoid flooding the main event loop of my app, I would like to make use of child processes / microservices to isolate each major task into its own process.

Ideally, the process segregation would look something like this:

```
Main Process
|-Data Source A
|  |- Data Downloading Microservice
|  |- Data Parsing Microservice
|  |- Main Computation Microservice
|-Data Source B
|  |- Data Downloading Microservice
|  |- Data Parsing Microservice
|  |- Main Computation Microservice
...
```

From what I currently understand, data piping and communication between each of these processes would be limited, and when the time comes to access a specific piece of information from one of the `Data Source` child processes, I would have to send a message from the `Main Process` to the `Data Source` process, and then have the `Data Source` process send a message to one of its microservices, and then pass that data all the way back up.

Is there an easier way to do this? For instance, **being able to store a table of process ids for each sub process in a lookup table and be able to directly send messages to and from that process without going through the one that initially spawned it**?

Comment: There are "lots" of different ways to do this, and too many for a simple explanation. If you really want more "free" communication between different processes then you probably want something along the lines of a message queue to receive and dispatch between it's different clients. Trying to set up rules in the processes themselves would probably be too cumbersome, so I would be looking more at some sort of "broker" to act like a "message bus" in anything other than the smallest scale. Look for material on that topic.

Comment: @NeilLunn Exactly the type of thing I was looking for, just wasn't familiar with the terminology. Thank you!